# Android Studio Listeners causing errors

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to implement a listener to monitor all clicks on a marker (Google Maps API) to allow for a function to be called upon a marker click event trigger. However each time I include the event listener code the application crashes.

Event Listener - setOnMarkerClickListener

How do I correctly implement this listener and handle crashes?

The code that I have already used is:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(marker.equals(ibrox)){
                    Log.w("Click", "test");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
```

I expect the program to operate without crashing and for the function to log the "Test".

Edit:
Value of ibrox variable -

```
private static final LatLng ibrox = new LatLng(55.8522161, -4.3138359);
```

Entire Code:

```
package com.example.googlemaps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final LatLng ibrox = new LatLng(55.8522161, -4.3138359);
    private Marker mIbrox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(marker.equals(ibrox)){
                    Log.w("Click", "test");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(40.7589, -73.9851);
        mIbrox = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(ibrox)
                .title("Ibrox"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in a place"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please make sure that mMap is not null.
you need to set the listener inside the onMapReady method.

follow this example:-
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(marker.equals(ibrox)){
                    Log.w("Click", "test");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(40.7589, -73.9851);
        mIbrox = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(ibrox)
                .title("Ibrox"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in a place"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to move

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() { @Override public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub if(marker.equals(ibrox)){ Log.w("Click", "test"); return true; } return false; } });
```

To onMapReady() method.